# Вставить HTML код в видео плэер в сообщение на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, парсер, видео, html, php

Хочу добавить в пост сайт на WordPress видео, для этого использую плэер videojs и чтобы он его воспроизвел ему нужна прямая ссылка на видео т.е.

```
[videojs mp4="http://site.com/video.mp4"]
```

он так работает, но в основном все сайты защищаются и генерируют "свои" внутренние ссылки на видео, с помощью safefrom я понял как спарсить эту "свою" прямую ссылку и для этого использую другой плагин парсера - wpws (WP Web Scraper) он по параметрам вытягивает мне нужную ссылку, я ее в текстовом виде вижу [wpws url="http://site.com/videos.html" selector=""]

Я попробовал вот так:

```
[videojs mp4=[wpws url="http://site.com/video.html" selector=""]],
```

при такой записи он видео не грузит и после видео ставит "]",
но ничего не получилось. Т.е. это нужно как-то на php делать, чего я не знаю.
т.е. нужно на пхп записать в переменную полученную ссылку от 1й функции и потом вставить ее во 2ю функцию, если можно избежать ПХП, то буду очень благодарен.
я если честно даже не знаю как это на wordpress сделать пробовал еще вот так:

```
$UrlVideo = [wpws url="http://site.com/video.html" selector=""]
[videojs mp4=$UrlVideo]
```

но как вы понимаете он мне все это и выдал в сообщении :)

Comment: Лично я ничего не понял. Переформулируйте вопрос.

Comment: хотя по примерчикам что-то понятно становится, ваша проблема в том что в WP сначала выполняется VideoJS по коду а потом только WPWS либо ковыряйтесь и меняйте их местами, либо нужно будет писать свой скрипт который будет принимать [videojs mp4=$UrlVideo] и делать необходимые действия.

Comment: Я переписал сообщение.
А как их поменять местами или как можно использовать переменные?
И почему-то он мне елси тег в тег засунуть выдает после ввсего прочего "]"

Comment: @Manitikyl, если нужно что-то уточнить, используйте комментарии.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $link = do_shortcode("[wpws url="http://site.com/video.html" selector=""]");
  echo(do_shortcode("[videojs mp4=$link]");
?>
```

Вот что мне нужно было - этот код работает, но теперь нужно додуматься как вставить его в Пост.